# Can't connect from outside to mongo

Tags: mongodb, debian

Hello I am trying to deploy my first MEAN app.

All works but on localhost.

From outside I can see front-end (angular2)

My problem is that i can't login into my app from outside. When I am trying to create account or login to exist acc I have

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This is my mongod.conf

```
# mongod.conf

# Where to store the data.

# Note: if you run mongodb as a non-root user (recommended) you may
# need to create and set permissions for this directory manually,
# e.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the mongodb user.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true
smallfiles=true

port = 27017

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces. 
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

# Disables write-ahead journaling
# nojournal = true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
#auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
#httpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Replication Options

# in replicated mongo databases, specify the replica set name here
#replSet=setname
# maximum size in megabytes for replication operation log
#oplogSize=1024
# path to a key file storing authentication info for connections
# between replica set members
#keyFile=/path/to/keyfile
```

And there is my config.json file

```
{
    "connectionString": "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mydb",
    "apiUrl": "http://localhost:4000",
    "secret": "REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR OWN SECRET, IT CAN BE ANY STRING"
}
```

I am using debian jessie

Comment: Could you provide more details, what you mean by `deploy`? What is changed? Could you also provide your nginx configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from your description, that your MongoDB is not deployed on localhost. If this is the case, you need to update your configuration.

Pay attention to the *bind_ip* parameter (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/). If you deploy your app on different server, mongodb-server public IP should go here. Application connectionString need to be updated as well to reflect correct IP.

But make sure, your security options are correctly set when deploying publicly (at least authentication https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/)!

Comment: I have installed mongodb on my debian server where is also node etc. I am using nginx.

I see my front end from outside but when I am trying to login I am getting error conn refused